# Recreating UNI & MUL indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, diff

I'm doing a MySQL differ, to help update my tables from dev to production but I'm having a little trouble with the indexes.

I'm using `show full columns from table` to get the indexes/keys of the tables and comparing them, then building the necessary queries to update the first table.

I get the primary keys, that's working. But I've been reading and I still don't fully understand the other two possibilities, `MUL`, and `UNI`.

I read the man page..

> If Key is PRI, the column is a PRIMARY KEY or is one of the columns
>   in a multiple-column PRIMARY KEY.
>
> If Key is UNI, the column is the first column of a unique-valued index
>   that cannot contain NULL values.
>
> If Key is MUL, multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted
>   within the column. The column is the first column of a nonunique index
>   or a unique-valued index that can contain NULL values.

Here's what I've currently got, if it's somehow relevant.

```
        if($key1 != $key2){
            if($key1['PRI'] != $key2['PRI']){
                // remove any existing primary keys 
                $results[$table_name][] = "ALTER TABLE $table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;";
                // add the new primary keys
                $results[$table_name][] = "ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD CONSTRAINT pk_$table_name PRIMARY KEY (".implode(",", $key2['PRI']).")";
            }
            if($key1['MUL'] != $key2['MUL']){
                // what to do here?
            }
            if($key1['UNI'] != $key2['UNI']){
                // what to do here?
            }
        }
```

I'm guessing I can do something like this for the `UNI`: `ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_myKey UNIQUE (indexColumn)` ..is that correct?

How about the `MUL`tiple keys? What's the syntax for that?

**What is the MySQL syntax to create a the `MUL` and `UNI` type keys?**

Thank you.

Comment: You are right about the UNI for the multiple keys it is like: `alter table  blah add constraint pk_something primary key (field1, field2)`

Comment: @JorgeCampos - Thank you, but that's the exact syntax I'm using for `PRI` type keys. Are they interchangeable or does my primary key query need adjustment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh...

```
                    switch($type){
                        case "PRI":
                            $ret[] = $add ?
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`$col`);" :
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` DROP PRIMARY KEY;" ;
                            break;
                        case "MUL":
                            $ret[] = $add ?
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ADD UNIQUE (`$col`);" :
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` DROP INDEX `$col`;" ;
                            break;
                        case "UNI":
                            $ret[] = $add ?
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ADD INDEX (`$col`);" :
                                "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` DROP INDEX `$col`;" ;
                            break;
                    }
```